# How auto layout constraints working with SwiftUI Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, swiftui

As SwiftUI framework has been released by Apple and there is no storyboards are available.

Is Auto Layout Constrains removed or still there to fit UI dynamically all screens sizes?

Comment: did you try to run it? did you try to drag and drop elements?

Comment: Since few days my mac isn't working.. Just watching videos and reading articles for SwiftUI and got this doubt? However if I drag and drop element on canvas or editor it going to generate code, but I am asking here about How Constraints Working with SwiftUI? Thank you.

Comment: did you saw any constraints on SwiftUI videos?

Answer (score -4):

Auto layout will help keep the button central in different orientations and devices. It is a constraint-based layout system that allows developers to create an adaptive interface, that responds appropriately to changes in screen size and device orientation

**How to fix Auto Layout problems:**, please follow this link:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-fix-auto-layout-problems